# what is diffrence between Response.write and Response.output.write

Tags: asp.net

what is difference between Response.write and Response.output.write please give me example

Answer (score 7):

`Response.Output.Write` allows you to format the string before outputting, `Response.Write` simply writes it out as is.

[`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.write.aspx) will output exactly what you pass in.

[`Response.Output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.output%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) exposes the underlying [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=VS.100).aspx), so [`Response.Output.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.write%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has many more overloads, some with `String.Format` functionality.

Comment: @Russell - expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. `Response.Write` is a convenience accessor to `Response.Output.Write`.

You could have found out this by yourself if you installed [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and looked up the class `HttpResponse` (in the assembly `System.Web`).